# Injecting problem - missing parent constructor call

Tags: php, symfony, oop, dependency-injection, symfony-3.4

I am trying to inject my BaseService within antoher service where I need to call my repository that I wrote in BaseService.

I think it's pretty simple thing but it marks __construct part with :

> Missing parent constructor call

I made that logic in BaseService and it works

```
class BaseService
{
    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    public $container;
    public $em;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em        = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository|\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
     */
    public function getMyDataRepository()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository(MyData::class);
    }
}
```

and my other service:

```
class DataService extends AbstractAdmin
{
    public function __construct(BaseService $baseService)
    {
        $this->baseService = $baseService;
    }

    public function getTransactions(Card $card)
    {
        return $this->getMyDataRepository()
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->getQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: try $this->baseService->getMyDataRepository() instead of $this->getMyDataRepository() in DateService

Comment: Does AbstractAdmin happen to have a constructor?  If so then that would explain the error message.

Comment: It does not but it's needed there because I am using SonataAdmin. So I am looking for alternative.. @Cerad

Comment: Tried. It's the same error.  @Rawburner

Comment: @develops - Don't know what the means but you get the error when one class extends another and does not call the parent constructor (if one exists).  Recheck your code.  The thing about getMyDataRepository is another error but you won't reach it until the constructor issue is solved.

Comment: AbstractAdmin from Sonata has a constructor: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/src/Admin/AbstractAdmin.php you need to call this in DataService

Comment: What is making the constructor with "Missing parent constructor call". Where are you seeing this message? Is it a PHP error, an exception, a static analysis tool warning? I'm guessing it's a static analysis tool warning, and would like to know which tool is providing this. Is it coming from PhpStorm?

Answer (score 8):

I found an answer.

I did it like this:

```
public $baseService;

public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, BaseService $baseService)
{
    parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
    $this->baseService = $baseService;
}
```

As Abstract Admin has its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add parent constructor of AbstractAdmin on DataService.

```
class DataService extends AbstractAdmin
{

    public function __construct(BaseService $baseService)
    {
        parent::__construct(AbstractAdmin dependencies goes here);
        $this->baseService = $baseService;
    }

    public function getTransactions(Card $card)
    {
        return $this->getMyDataRepository()
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->getQuery();
    }
```

I dont know which dependencies need your AbstractAdmin

Comment: Alas the comments make it clear that AbstractAdmin has no constructor.  Though I suppose it might itself extend yet another class.